# Apply Gradient background color and image at the same time

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Is it possible to apply background-image and background-color to a text field at the same time.

What I was trying to achieve is : Show an icon at the right corner of text field. Also Make that text field a little bit gradient using the style

`background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , white, #D6E5F4) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes; you can apply color & image at same time .You have to write like this:

```
background: url("image.png") no-repeat 0 0,-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , white, #D6E5F4);
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/7yMhX/